# Is an AntMiner S7 batch 14 good?

Tags: mining-hardware

I was looking at my new Butterfly Jalapeños while logging on to my Bitcoin Wallet (My new one as I still haven't found the old one.) and realized how inefficient the Butterfly Jalapeños were. So I started looking up Bitcoin miners. I came across the AntMiner S7 and thought it looked amazing, I also calculated that it would make over $4 USD every day for a total of over $100 every month. I did some more research and could find no problems with it. I was wondering if anyone knew of ANY problems of any kind with the AntMiner S7's. Thanks for the help.

-GoldNugget8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious problem, it appears to me, is that they cost $1200. If you make $4 per day (assuming that's net profit after paying for electricity), it'll take about a year to pay for itself. That's assuming the mining difficulty stays the same for a year, which it almost certainly will not; in the last 12 months (March 2015 to March 2016), difficulty has more than tripled.

Unless the value of Bitcoin rises substantially (faster than difficulty), I'd be skeptical of coming out ahead.

Comment: Noise and heat is also another problem.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if i sounded kind of harsh when i said "I don't see why you didn't post it as an answer though."